# How to use Verify() for a specific expected result?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

**Context**

I am using AutoFixtue's `GuardClauseAssertion`to verify the method under test is throwing the expected ArgumentNullException if any of the method call arguments is null:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var assertion = new GuardClauseAssertion(fixture);
var myMethodInfo = ...
assertion.Verify(myMethodInfo);
```

The method under test looks like:

```
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p1, IList<T> p2, Func<T> p3, string p4)
{
     if (p1 == null || p2 == null...)
     {
          yield break;
     }

     // Return non-empty IEnumerable here...
}
```

**Question**

In my particular case the expected behavior is not throwing `ArgumentNullException`, instead return with empty `IEnumerable<T>`, so I would like to Verify against this result.

How can I customize the existing Verify default behaviour to accomplish this goal?

Comment: AutoFixture has quite an extensive test suite for it's components. Maybe [this test](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/9dc8fa09aa42618df17986b3899f6f3803e2f557/Src/IdiomsUnitTest/GuardClauseAssertionTest.cs#L146) will help you with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas Many thanks. On that test the DelegatingBehaviorExpectation is helper test class but anyway, I can start with the code.

Comment: What does the SUT look like? Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue - in this case the method you wish to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GuardClauseAssertion` checks if a method parameter is `null` or not. As you mentioned, your *particular* case does not fit that behavior, so there is no need in using `GuardClauseAssertion`. Just create a *special* test that covers your *special* behavior.

In the same time, if you use the *assembly-* or [*class-wide* guard clause verification](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/40bbc124e2b388ed8081abde19d846932f5111bd/Src/IdiomsUnitTest/Scenario.cs#L42), you might need to exclude your particular method from the verification list. AFAIR, AutoFixture does not provide any API for that; you should just use LINQ.

Comment: well, I thought this is an "idiom" so please do not give up so fast, It worth to give the chance to not reinvent the wheel and reuse the existing infrastructure in AutoFixture, and then write one line assertion instead of a bunch of copy and pasted tests.

Answer (score 1):

A method like the above `MyMethod` is not what `GuardClauseAssertion` was originally designed to cover.

Originally, AutoFixture was developed as a helper library to do test-driven development (TDD), which is all about getting fast feedback on object design and implementation details. Because it's an opinionated library, AutoFixture tends to **enhance TDD feedback**. When it becomes awkward to test a SUT with AutoFixture, it could be an indication that there's a deeper design issue.
I'd be inclined to think that this is the case here.

## Nulls are a mistake

Like [sir Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare), I believe that null references are a mistake. They're a part of C#, so we have to deal with their potential presence, but I don't think that it should change the fundamental principle that `null` isn't a valid value. It's a mistake to call a method with a null argument.

When a client developer looks at a method signature like

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Sut(Bar bar, Baz baz, Qux qux)
```

at that level, there's not enough information to enable him or her to deduce whether or not `null` is allowed for a particular argument. In this particular context, you may already 'know' that they're all allowed to be `null`, but a client developer (co-worker, or yourself in the future) may not know this for all methods.

Consider another method:

```
public Foo CounterExample(Bar bar, Corge corge, Garply garply)
```

Is it OK to call `CounterExample` with a `null bar`? What about a `null corge`? It could turn out that it's okay if `bar` and `garply` is `null`, but if `corge` is `null`, it's going to throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

## Design with abstractions

When an entire code base/API is designed like that (i.e. with no consistency), then the only way for a client developer to get answers to questions like *which arguments can be null?* is to read the implementation code.

This slows down development, because instead of being able to rely on abstractions, everyone can only work on the level of implementation details. It also makes a code base brittle, because client developers end up writing code that depends on implementation details. Change the implementation, and client code breaks.

One way to solve that problem is to remove the question entirely. Instead of allowing client developers to wonder *which arguments can be null?*, you can, with a sweeping generalisation declare that in your code base, `null` is never an acceptable or valid value.

So, whenever a method receives a `null` argument, it should throw an `ArgumentNullException`, and that's what `GuardClauseAssertion` is designed to verify.

## Postel's law

What about [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), then? Doesn't it say to be liberal in what we accept? If we can correctly handle a `null p1` by returning an empty `IEnumerable<T>`, shouldn't we do that?

Yes, if that is truly the appropriate design, then that's what Postel's law says, but I think that it should be surfaced in the design. If an argument is optional, this should be modelled with method overloads, not by allowing `null` arguments:

```
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>()
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p1)
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p2)
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p3)
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p4)
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p1, IList<T> p2)
// etc...
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p1, IList<T> p2, Func<T> p3)
IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(IList<T> p1, IList<T> p2, Func<T> p3, string p4)
```

This makes it clear from the method signature(s) alone that all the arguments are optional, and that saves the client developer from having to read through the implementation details of the method in question.

This may add a bit more work to the implementation work, but saves work later. Since most code is read more than it's written, this optimises for the critical path (i.e. *reading*).

In this particular case, since all four arguments are optional, there are quite a few combinations available. In such a case, I'd consider refactoring the design to a Fluent Builder instead, but before I'd do that, I'd seriously reconsider if I actually need that many arguments to a single method.

Comment: All true. However your are answered in very detail to an other question: "Are null parameters considered an error or not?",  This was not the question. We know the answer. It would enough just stating it as a professional opinion. (which is related to the question), without reasoning (which is out of topic) and instead say at least one sentence about the question. As an open source lib author you make your design decisions. It's not hard to imagine, the majority of us not as lucky, there are existing code compatibility constrains, non professional outer decisions, company legacy, policy etc.

Comment: @g.pickardou Please accept my apologies if I failed to communicate that you can't extend `GuardClauseAssertion` in the way you would like. My answer was only an attempt to explain the reasoning behind that design decision. The answer by Sergey Shushlyapin is, I believe, the correct answer to the question, and I up-voted it accordingly even before I added my own answer.